# Wrapping a web app up as an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

The question says it all-how hard is it?  Is it allowed?  Any other comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy -- just use a UIWebView. I don't know of any rules against it. I have one out there that got approved.

Answer (score 0):

Although apps that are just a webview may get through to the store, you can make your app feel like an iphone app by just doing a very minimal amount of work. I think the best bet is to at least have a tab controller with the webview in one tab and an "About" page in another. Or possibly tab views that point to the various sections of the webpage. I think you and your users will be more pleased with the result if you do just a little UIKit stuff.

Comment: I have never heard apps being rejected for just being a web view. Do you have any references?

Comment: No, I actually heard it from a co-worker. I will edit my answer to only contain info i'm sure of.