# iPhone Web App to Native app using Airplay SDK?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Has anyone had any experience of this?  Is it easy?  I know very little C, but all I want to do is package the web app as a native app.  Is that allowed by Apple anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always just have users click the little "Add to Home Screen" button in Safari, but of course that isn't in the App Store.

Comment: This question asks something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306925/wrapping-a-web-app-up-as-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

Airplay SDK is a C/C++ programming environment. Its broad support for C/C++ standard libraries makes it easy to bring existing C/C++ codebases to the platform, including Open Source codebases.

It's possible to bring "web apps" to Airplay SDK, but you'll have to do a certain amount of legwork - for example, finding and porting an Open Source JavaScript runtime to Airplay SDK. Similarly for an HTML rendering engine. Ideaworks Labs can already provide various scripted runtime engines that  work with Airplay SDK (Lua, Python, Ruby) but JavaScript is not currently on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning the airplay sdk now. You can find the information in the [www.airplaysdk.com](http://www.airplaysdk.com).

There are a lot of examples in the airplaysdk, so you can learn it easily.
I have wrotten a small game use airplaysdk, i think it works well and worth to learning.